# How can I replace text just before the EOL in vi?

Tags: vi

I'm trying to do a search in replace in `vi`.  The usual:

```
:s/yes/no/gc
```

isn't cooperating.  The "yes" is the last piece of text on the line.  If I search for text isn't part of the last word the command works.  But none of the following seem to be cooperating:

```
:s/ye/no/gc
:s/yesCTRLVCTRLM/noCTRLVCTRLM/gc
```

The file is a DOS formated (EOL) file.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:s/yes$/no/gc Should do the trick

$ is the character representing the end of the line. ^ would represent the start of the line.

Comment: Strangely, it didn't work (as I too, would've expected it too).

Comment: @Jamie Thats odd, it works just fine here using `yes bla yes bla yes` as test line, and `:s/yes$/no/g`. Only changes the last yes into no. Maybe it's the DOS formating, but then I'm surprised your ^M solution didn't work.

Comment: Truthfully, I'm not a power `vi` user; and it's really not that big a hassle to jump out to a shell and use `sed`, which does work.  I was hoping I'd provided enough information to understand the idiosyncrasies of `vi`.  Guess not.  Thanks for the response though.